# .Net MVC - Background process implementation with HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, background-process

I am looking for something like a background process in MVC.

Requirement is I should run a background process/thread in .Net MVC application, which will be async and doesn't wait for the action in the foreground/ UI. Similar to fire and forget.

I am trying to use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem for the same. Can this be used or anything else is recommended ? I am armature in MVC, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use background job in controller `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is normal solution.

For examle, start backgroud action and foget

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Action<CancellationToken> workItem = SomeBackGroundWork;
            
            // start background work and forget
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);

            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }

        private async void SomeBackGroundWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000,cancellationToken);

            // or you can do http request to web site
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://google.com",  new StringContent(""), cancellationToken);

            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just noticed this in google regarding HostingEnvironment - "Note that QueueBackgroundWorkItem can only be called inside an ASP.NET managed app domain." 
Any idea what does it mean ? I will be deploying my application using IIS, app pool

Comment: In IIS it will be work well. In this solution use CancellationToken - it mean when application stop, all your background threads get signal about stopping.

Comment: Sure , Thanks a ton !